How to call function from another file in shell for magisk module?
I am unable to use function from another file. The main file is install.sh and the functions are placed in the file functions.sh
The installation results failed when I source the functions.
I have used the following code and the installation crashes.
main file calling function: install.sh
#!/system/bin/sh
MODDIR=${0%/*}

echo "running chmod"
chmod +x install.sh

echo "adding functions.sh"
. functions.sh
echo "function retrieved"

TEXT="I am here"

check $text

another file containing function: functions.sh
check(){
    TESTTEXT=$1
    echo "${TESTEXT}"
    return 0
}

The output is
-Copying zip to temp directory
-Installing module.zip
-Device is system-as-root
running chmod
adding functions.sh
! Installation failed

I have also tried with
source /functions.sh
. functions.sh
. ./functions.sh

Why are you doing /function.sh that means its in the root folder. If its in the same folder just do source function.sh or source ./functions.sh

I tried both source ./functions.sh but the installation fails when it reaches on the source ./functions.sh line.

then try source /full/path/to/function.sh (what you did would normally work, something is not right) . Do you see any error messages? Good luck.

What is the error message that you are getting?  Syntax is good. I would suggest comment out all other code and first write a bare minimum function doing echo and call it and proceed from there. Also what do you mean by installation fails ??

the installation fails when it reaches on the sourc "Fails" how? What happens? Does the execution stop? What is the exit code? Please post the full verbatim output of execution of install.sh script with set -x, like sh -x ./install.sh. Why are you setting executable of install.sh from the scriupt itself? Are you using bash or busybox or sh? check $text text is unquoted, so it will be word split, so TESTTEXT will only contain I, the output will be just I. Are you expecting this behavior? If not, research word splitting and check your scripts with shellcheck .

I added echo before adding the source and after adding the source. The echo before source is displayed and execution stops. The echo after adding the source isn't displayed.

The program is executed in busybox's ash as mentioned
"Every single shell script running in the context of Magisk will be executed in BusyBox’s ash shell with standalone mode enabled. For what is relevant to 3rd party developers, this includes all boot scripts and module installation scripts."

Add set -x on top of the script and show full output. Most probably, as of given information, your files contain different contents than presented. For example your functions has exit

The installation crashes with no output when set -x ./install.sh is used. I added echo "running script now" before sh -x and it loops there

What do you mean by set -x ./install.sh is used?

You are running the script via the shell /system/bin/sh.  If this is indeed Bash, then it will run in POSIX-conformance mode.  On the other hand, you tag [busybox], and the shell it provides is ash, not Bash.  ash is a lightweight shell from the Bourne family, where "lightweight" means in part that it does not provide extra features such as Bash, Zsh, and other members of the family do.

The installation results failed when I source the functions.

Not surprising.  The source command is not part of the traditional Bourne shell language.  The standard spelling for that command is ..  Thus, whether you are running ash or Bash in POSIX-conformance mode, you are probably looking for:
. ./functions.sh

Note also that ./functions.sh will be resolved relative to the script's working directory, not its own installation directory.  This may be a problem for you, and if so, it is quite possibly beyond ash's capabilities to resolve.  Your best bet might well be simply to put the function(s) directly in install.sh.

MODDIR=${0%/*}
chmod +x install.sh
echo "adding source now"
. ./functions.sh
echo "source added"
`
The output is
adding source now
installation failed

@SudeepKunwar  Please update the body of your question with that information, properly formatted. Thanks and good luck.
